# Почему пропадает подсветка синтаксиса в CLion?

Tags: ide, clion

Всем привет!

Суть проблемы в том что в CLion спонтанно пропадает подсветка синтаксиса, подсказки вроде остаются, а сама подсветка пропадает. Подсветка возвращается после 10 минут или после перезапуска CLion. Как это возможно исправить?

**СLion до:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**СLion после:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: И там, и там код разукрашен. Да по разному, но он разноцветный. Поэтому, Я бы не говорил, что подсветка попадает. Она просто меняется.

Comment: Вы правы, но цвет остается только у ключевых слов переменных и include, а у всего остального цвета  пропадают, что занимают большую часть кода и это очень не приятно.

Comment: Похоже, что падает lsp/clangd часть. Что делать? Искать подходящую версию или просто, как все нормальные люди, перейти на что то более адекватное.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под словом - "что-то более адекватное"?

Comment: visual studio, vscode, vim/nvim+lsp, sublime+lsp. В Вашем случае Qt, возможно стоит посмотреть на QtCreator. Я его недавно трогал - он стал достаточно хорош.

Comment: Почти все из этого я уже пробовал, но лучшим из всего этого остается CLion и QtCreator. CLion мне больше нравится и хотелось бы работать с ним,  но это проблема очень сильно мешает

Comment: я пробовал clion. даже компания предлагала лицензию купить. Но когда я понял, что я чаще запускаю вим, что бы поправить код, то сказал, что это мне не нужно. Я быстрее запускаю вим и фикшу, чем запускается clion.

Comment: Это, конечно, вариант, но это не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Баги/краши ide - это к разработчикам. Я могу только предложить альтернативу, которая бесплатная и, хотя бы, работает. Баги Qtcreator, vim в принципе может попытаться каждый решить, так как есть сорцы. А с clion могу только посочувствовать.